# How to run command while installing the NuGet package through dotnet CLI

Tags: c#, .net, package, nuget, .net-standard

I have to create a NuGet package. the package should be designed so that it should run the exe while installing the package and have to use `dotnet cli`.
I read some article that suggest add Init.ps1 in /tools folder. But it's not working with `dotnet cli`.

Comment: NuGet packages haven't been able to run code when they are installed for a long time now (ever since SDK-style projects happened). This sounds like an XY problem: *why* do you need to run an exe when the package is installed?

Comment: Before nuget we were providing installer. that places some file in default location and start 1 service. Now through NuGet we are able to place the files but now have to start the service while installing package.

Comment: That isn't how nuget works: you can't install and start a process on the consumer's machine! Nuget is for DLLs which get added to projects as references (and some other things, like templates and `dotnet` tools). They certainly aren't for installing services.

Comment: I'd be horrified if installing a Nuget pack in my project would start running processes. That's terrifying.

Comment: @canton7 I got your point. I think we need to change our design. Thanks